# Table column spacing not even - Stata to LaTeX

Tags: tables, vertical-spacing, stata

I am using the following Stata code to export a table containing the means of 4 variables over 5 period.

```
est clear
forv p=1/5 {
    eststo filenum`p': quietly estpost summarize x1111 x22222 x33333333 x444444444444 if filenum==`p'
    }

esttab filenum* using "C_centcomp.tex", replace title(Minimum Working Example\label{tab1}) cells("mean(pattern(1 1 1 1 1) fmt(2))") collabels(none) label booktabs nomtitle nonotes ///
addnotes("\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth} \footnotesize \smallskip Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \end{minipage}")
```

This is the resulting LaTeX code.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Minimum Working Example\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}\\
\midrule
x1111              &        0.41&        0.41&        0.41&        0.43&        0.43\\
x22222         &        0.05&        0.05&        0.05&        0.05&        0.05\\
x33333333           &        0.54&        0.54&        0.55&        0.55&        0.56\\
x444444444444        &        0.14&        0.14&        0.14&        0.14&        0.14\\
\midrule
Observations        &        1527&        1478&        1429&        1297&        1180\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth} \footnotesize \smallskip Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah\end{minipage}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

After running the LaTeX code you will notice that the spacing between columns is not even. Can you  please suggest the modifications to be made in the Stata code so that the column spacing is correctly reflected in the LaTeX code. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried changing `\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}` to `\begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}`?

Comment: actually the spacing may or may not be even depending on the relative size of `\linewidth`  compared with the table content. It's always best to post your examples as small but complete documents that may be used to reproduce the error and test answers.  Here can't you simply move the notes after the tabular rather than in a full width multicolumn?

Comment: Thanks Mico and David. Mico's suggestion does not work. David, my preference is to keep everything (including notes) in one place i.e. within the Stata code. I'll post the entire LaTeX code shortly using a MWE so you can see the packages I am using. I assume you don't require the entire Stata code.

Comment: @Hugh, a statement such as "does not work" is not actionable. *What* exactly doesn't work? Is the table maybe still too wide? Or is the `minipage` not wide enough?  Do you get warning and/or error messages? If so, what do they say? Is the table maybe still too wide? Or is the `minipage` not wide enough?

Comment: Thanks Mico. A correction. I just reran the code with your suggestion `\begin{minipage}{0.65\linewidth}` and the column spacing problem is solved. However the table is a bit narrow on the page. So I tried `\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}` but the spacing issue begins to appear. Is there a way to dynamically set the table to adjust within the page?

Comment: I would appreciate suggestions on more efficient ways to incorporate Stata results into LaTeX. I am not particularly tied to using `esttab` (created by Ben Jann) to export Stata results although I have used it recently. I am also prepared to include some of the code directly in LaTeX itself rather than indirectly through Stata (e.g. table legends).  Any useful threads on the subject would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you employ the machinery of the [threepartable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package. That way, the legend can be formatted automatically in such a way that its width equals that of the associated `tabular` environment, while avoiding any complications that may arise from placing the legend in a `minipage` of some prespecified width.

Incidentally, I can see no good reason for placing the column headers -- (1), (2), etc -- in `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` "wrappers". Is this done by Stata?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}

% Part 1: the caption
\caption{Minimum Working Example\tnote{a}}\label{tab1}

% Part 2: the tabular-like environment (with \tnote{...} directives)
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{5}{c} @{}}
\toprule
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) \\
\midrule
x1111          &   0.41&   0.41&   0.41&   0.43&   0.43\\
x22222         &   0.05&   0.05&   0.05&   0.05&   0.05\\
x33333333      &   0.54&   0.54&   0.55&   0.55&   0.56\\
x444444444444  &   0.14&   0.14&   0.14&   0.14&   0.14\\
\midrule
Observations\tnote{b}   &   1527&   1478&   1429&   1297&   1180\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\footnotesize 

% Part 3: the table notes (with \item[...] directives
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft] 
\item[a] Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\item[b] blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico. Yes, Stata creates the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrappers. The only Stata code I have used to export the results is what I sent in my first post above. I like the table you have created above. It looks very neat. As I mentioned in my previous comment, I am looking for an efficient way to export Stata results (summary statistics, t-tests, regressions, multiple panels, etc.) into LaTeX. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks.